# Как рассчитать последовательность значений, если известны 2 точки?

Tags: математика

Как рассчитать последовательность точек? 
Если знаю, что, например при x = 900, y = 650. И знаю, что x = 450, y = 350.

Я думаю, что стоит решить систему уравнений:
y1 = ax1 + b
y2 = ax2 + b    - это верное решение?

Comment: Известно, что зависимость линейная?

Answer (score 1):

Да при x1,y1 и x2,y2, но существует погрешность
Если у вас n то лучше считать полиномы n-1 степени, по схожему методу, затем для определения коэффициентов a,b, и т.д. метод Гаусса

Comment: Да, мне желательно найти все пары значений от x1 до x2.

Comment: @VitaljaB. если идти через полином первой степени то получится прямая и на ней все точки последовательности

Comment: можно мини-пример расчета? что по поводу погрешности? будет ли большая?

Answer (score 1):

Если известно, что последовательность линейна, а точек у вас всего две, то все просто: между точками - интерполяция, за пределами точек - экстраполяция.

Comment: да, линейная. какой из методов точнее? который предложен мной (система) или через интерполяцию?

Comment: Это по сути одно и то же, просто записанное разными способами